vscode change webpack icon rule
Since I have a monorepo project I need to do some fine tuning configuration for webpack, and I need to create different files.
For instance I need to create a webpack.react.common.js file, and I wanted to have a webpack icon for clarity.
I tried to change user settings like this but webpack is not among the recognized files association:
"workbench.iconTheme": "vs-seti",
"files.associations": {
     "webpack*.common.js": "webpack"
  },
"editor.codeLens": true

Is there a way to achieve this. I'm using vs-seti (as in the config)

I think "webpack" is not a valid format for files.associations... Then your webpack-files are actually .js files. What kind of file-"icon" are you hoping to achieve?

@SwissCodeMen yes, webpack is not a valid format. I was hoping to change the icon from JS to the webpack one, but I can't do it using the file association. So I was wondering if other solutions where available

With a little research, I found this documentation with some examples. So try out the following code snipped in your settings.json, to change the file-icon of webpack-js-files to webpack (based on this list, webpack is a supported icon):
"vsicons.associations.files": [{
    "icon": "webpack",
    "extensions": [
        "webpack*.common.js"
    ],
    "filename": true,
    "format": "svg"
}]

Let me know, if that works!

It is a different icon theme tho (vscode-icons and not vs-seti). And wildcards are not allowed in the extensions array (as far I know)

Have you tried with two ** in front of the extension? "**/webpack*.common.js": "webpack"

Yes, I tried it. I confirm you that you have to explicitly specify the files
